# Linker Script - Placing a section at the end of a memory region

Tags: c++, c, memory, linker, linker-scripts

I have searched far and wide for how to do this and have failed to come up with an answer.

My memory layout is as follows:

```
Fake Address | Section
     0       |  text
     7       |  relocate
    15       |  bss
    23       |  stack
```

At the end of the Stack I place the Heap. Which grows up and the stack is a full descending stack for the ARM chip I am using.

Now, what I want to do is place a single section, let's call it `.persist`, into my ram memory. I want it to reside at the very end of RAM and I want to program this into my linker script. However, this `.persist` section's size is not defined by me but is computed by the compiler from the symbols that it contains.

So far I've not come up with a good way to do it. Since I know the RAM start address and SIZE it would be trivial to calculate where the section needs to go if I knew the section size. However, according to [the GNU linker documentation (pg 74)](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/teaching/eecs373-f10/readings/Linker.pdf) it seems that:

> SIZEOF(section) Returns the size in bytes of the named
>   section, if that section has been allocated.
>   If the section has not been allocated when this is evaluated, the linker will
>   report an error.

so I can't work out the size of the section in the linker script (since I want to calculate the size BEFORE I place it/allocate it).

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19348569/911550

Comment: It is a partial solution but not what I'm after. It is still the closest anyone else has come to helping. Thanks!

Comment: This is solved (see my comment below).

Answer (score 7):

I was able to accomplish something similar by making linking a two-step process. 
First I compile the section in question to its own object file. In my case I had a metadata section generated from an assembly file. `gcc -c` will compile the source into object files, but not link them.

```
gcc -c  metadata.s  -o metadata.o
```

You could also build your whole program, then extract just the section in question with `objcopy`.

```
gcc -c  main.cc  -o main.o
objcopy --only-section=.metadata  main.o  metadata.o
```

Now I build and link the rest of the program, and include the object file among the linker's input.

```
gcc metadata.o  ../main.o  -o Program.elf  -T linkerscript.ld
```

The linker reads the section `.metadata` from the object file, and I can reference its size in the linker script.

Comment: It has been a long time since I last worked on this project but your answer seems the closest to making it possible. I will have to verify it before marking as correct but for now +1.

Comment: I'm missing the linker script that makes this possible. AFAICS, there is no way to reference the size of an *input* section in a linker script, but this answer suggests otherwise...

Answer (score 5):

I managed to solve it by calculating the size of the code by using the linker command: size.
In my Makefile i set SIZE to the size of the code. I then call cpp (the preprocessor) to calculate all absolute addresses (using c-syntax). I then link using the generated linkfile: tmp.ld

```
%.elf: %.o
    $(eval SIZE := $(shell arm-none-eabi-size -B $<  | tail -n 1 | awk -F ' ' '{print $$1}'))
    $(CC) -DSEG_SIZE=$(SIZE) -P -E -x c link.ld -o tmp.ld
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)
```

In the link.ld-file i can do all kinds of calculations (as SEG_SIZE is a constant):

```
#define SEG_LAST_ADDR 1234
#define MY_SEG        (SEG_LAST_ADDR - SEG_SIZE)

MEMORY
{
  bootloader     (rx)  : ORIGIN = MY_SEG,     LENGTH = SEG_SIZE
  ...
}
```

I finally link against the tmp.ld-file.

Comment: This is what I did when I need it --- it's vile, but it does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem
I did it this way

```
/* heap section */
.heap (NOLOAD):
{
    . = ALIGN(8);
     _sheap = .;
    . = . + HEAP_SIZE;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _eheap = .;
} > ram

_ram_end_ = ORIGIN(ram) + LENGTH(ram) -1 ;
_stack_size = _ram_end_ - _eheap ;

/* stack section */
.stack (NOLOAD): 
{
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _sstack = .;
    . = . + _stack_size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _estack = .;
} > ram

.LastSection (NOLOAD): /* for test in dump file */
{
    . = ALIGN(8);
} > ram
```

Comment: Though I did consider this the question is asking for the placement of a section at the end of ram such that the last byte of that section occupies the `_ram_end` address. From what I can see you are placing the stack at the end of the ram and the stack simply occupies all remaining bytes. I'm asking to do this with a section that, unlike the stack, has a static size which doesn't depend on the sizes of the other sections. Effectively, in this example your stack takes up all remaining memory in the RAM.

Answer (score -1):

You can force sections at specific locations.

For example in this Red Hat GNU Linker documentation [page](https://web.archive.org/web/20191218185104/https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/simple-example.html), you can define the .data section to start at address 0x8000000:

```
SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x10000;
  .text : { *(.text) }
  . = 0x8000000;
  .data : { *(.data) }
  .bss : { *(.bss) }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. However, this does not allow me to store my section so that it *ends at a particular address*. I want to get the size of my section, subtract it from an address giving me a result address and then place it at the result address. This way I can place my section, which has a variable size, **at the end** of my RAM memory block. I found this to not be possible and that is what the question is about.

Answer (score -2):

> what I want to do is place a single section, let's call it .persist, into my ram memory. I want it to reside at the very end of RAM and I want to program this into my linker script.

Linker script has special variable called [Location Counter](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/ld/Location-Counter.html#Location-Counter) which allows to modify the current address, and as such the size or address of a section or symbol, by creating gaps or holes in the address space.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. You have missed what I said after about the `SIZEOF` operator not giving you the size of the section **until** you *place it*. I need to get the size of the section **before** I place it for this to work.

Comment: The only workaround would be if I could place the section, get the size and then unplace it and move it elsewhere...