# load script to load a section at the top of a memory region

Tags: gcc, ld, linker-scripts

I'm working on a project for an embedded system, using an ARM M0.

A ROM application has to be created, whose sole purpose is to store stuff in rom, and initialize the data and bss sections whenever needed.

The loadscript so far is this:

```
MEMORY
{
  rom (rx): ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = 32K ; 
  ram (!rx): ORIGIN = 0x10000, LENGTH = 8K ; 
}

SECTION
{
  . = ORIGIN(rom) ;

  .text:
  {
    KEEP(*(.text)) ;
  } >.

  .data:
  {
    KEEP(*(.data)) ;
  } >ram AT>.

  .bss:
  {
    KEEP(*(.bss)) ;
  } > ram = 0x00
}
```

I want to change the loadscript so that the data and bss portions are loaded into ram at the top of the memory region, not at the bottom.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

As far as my understanding currently goes, this is simply not possible. One can, however, define a size, and use that calculate the starting address.

e.g.

```
_ram_data_size = 0x1000 ;
_ram_data_address = ORIGIN(ram) + LENGTH(ram) - _ram_data_size ;
_rom_data_address = 0x100 ;

SECTION
{
  .data _ram_data_address : AT _rom_data_address
  {
    KEEP(*(.data)) ;
  }
  ASSERT( SIZEOF(.data) <= _ram_data_size ) ;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! How did you figure out the `ORIGIN(ram)`/`LENGTH(ram)` syntax? I wanted it for calculating the top of stack, ie. `_estack = ORIGIN(ram) + LENGTH(ram);`, so I spent hours looking for the syntax for referencing the memory regions in the manual and on google, but had no luck before stumbling on to this. So, if you still happen to remember: Where did you find the syntax?

Comment: Okay, so it turns out I was just looking at an outdated version of the manual the whole time... oops.

Comment: All my knowledge stems from a lot of trial and even more error, and from this link: http://www.scoberlin.de/content/media/http/informatik/gcc_docs/ld_3.html

Comment: Ah, that's actually the exact (outdated) version I was looking at, and does not include the documentation on `ORIGIN(ram)` and `LENGTH(ram)`. I switched to https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/MEMORY.html, which includes them, when I realized I might be looking at an old version.