# How to get the size of an input section (to place it at the end of memory)

Tags: ld, linker-scripts

I have the following linker script:
`.data` & `.bss` are placed into ram, then a `.heap` section fills the remaining memory.

Now I want to add a `.noinit` section that always gets placed at the end of the memory. That is so it gets ignored by bootloaders and the like.

I still want my `.heap` section to occupy all available space between `.bss` and `.noinit`, but for this I need to know the size of the `.noinit` section.

A naive approach failed:

```
/* .bss section which is used for uninitialized data */
.bss (NOLOAD) :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sbss = . ;
    _szero = .;
    *(.bss .bss.*)
    *(COMMON)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = . ;
    _ezero = .;
} > ram

/* heap section */
.heap (NOLOAD) :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sheap = . ;
    . = ORIGIN(ram) + LENGTH(ram) - SIZEOF(.noinit);
    _eheap = . ;
}  > ram

/*
 * collect all uninitialized sections that go into RAM
 */
.noinit (NOLOAD) :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __noinit_start = .;
    *(.noinit)
    __noinit_end = .;
}  > ram
```

Here `SIZEOF(.noinit)` is always 0 because the section is defined after that statement.

But in fact what I want is `SIZEOF(*(.noinit))` - however this is a syntax error.

So how do I get the size of an input section without placing it into an output section first?

Comment: See some of the interesting answers/comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647590/linker-script-placing-a-section-at-the-end-of-a-memory-region

Comment: Answer here can get you what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55126837/3869724

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly kosher, but after digging through the [source code](https://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git) for GNU ld it looks like you can specify the address of section after it is defined.

The following linker script should give you the desired behavior:

```
MEMORY {
    ram   (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x10000, LENGTH = 0x0002000
}

SECTIONS {

    .bss (NOLOAD) : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sbss = . ;
        _szero = .;
        *(.bss .bss.*)
        *(COMMON)

        /* Note: Just for example - padding .bss by 0x100 bytes so its not empty */
        . = 0x100;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ebss = . ;
        _ezero = .;
    } > ram 

    /* create .noinit section */
    .noinit (NOLOAD): {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __noinit_start = .;

        /* Note: Just for example - padding .noinit by 0x100 bytes so its not empty */
        . = 0x100;

        *(.noinit)
        __noinit_end = .;
    }  > ram

    /* place .heap after .bss */
    .heap _ebss (NOLOAD) : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sheap = . ;
        . = ABSOLUTE(ORIGIN(ram) + LENGTH(ram) - SIZEOF(.noinit));
        _eheap = . ;
    }  > ram

    /* update .noinit to be placed at end of heap */
    .noinit _eheap (NOLOAD) : { } > ram
}
```

The output of an empty binary linked with the above script show the correct placement of sections and symbols:

```
echo | gcc -x c++ - -nostartfiles -T linkerScript.ld -Xlinker --orphan-handling=discard -fuse-ld=bfd  && objdump -th a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .bss          00000100  0000000000010000  0000000000010000  00001000  2**0
                  ALLOC
  1 .noinit       00000100  0000000000011f00  0000000000011f00  00001000  2**0
                  ALLOC
  2 .heap         00001e00  0000000000010100  0000000000010100  00001000  2**0
                  ALLOC
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000010000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000011f00 l    d  .noinit        0000000000000000 .noinit
0000000000010100 l    d  .heap  0000000000000000 .heap
0000000000010100 g       .heap  0000000000000000 _sheap
0000000000010000 g       .bss   0000000000000000 _sbss
0000000000010000 g       .bss   0000000000000000 _szero
0000000000010100 g       .bss   0000000000000000 _ebss
0000000000010100 g       .bss   0000000000000000 _ezero
0000000000011f00 g       .noinit        0000000000000000 __noinit_start
0000000000012000 g       .noinit        0000000000000000 __noinit_end
0000000000011f00 g       .heap  0000000000000000 _eheap
```

> **Note:** I couldn't find any documentation regarding this behavior so I can't guarantee this trick will work in future revisions of ld.

> **Note:** This trick doesn't work for the gold linker.